# google cloud speech to text api does not return complete reco text result

Tags: google-cloud-speech

My account is free tier of $300/12 months.

My audio file is in google cloud as .wav file (ja-JP, 16K, 16bit, mono channel, 10 min, 18 MB) and i follow https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech_transcribe_async_gcs-java to retrieve reco result. The complete reco text is expected to be 2942 characters.

However, api always retrieve back 1101 char and then stop without telling any err or reason.

Is it limit to free tier only or anything i missed ?

Thank you.